# Markdown preview and snippet editor not appearing when editing question

Tags: bug, questions, edits

For the last few days I've noticed that when editing questions to improve their formatting that the markdown preview no longer appears. This is a huge pain, especially when attempting to edit large questions which contain snippets.

It makes it doubly annoying when all you would need to do to fix the formatting of a large code block is open the snippet editor and click 'Tidy'.

Has this been done intentionally? If so, why? Is it possible that we could revert back to the old UI for editing a question?

For reference, [this is an image of a question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dils7.png) which contains a snippet that I'm trying to edit. And [this is how it appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIQ9u.png) when I click the edit button. Note the lack of preview and no snippet editor available.

Comment: What OS and browser?  Do you have any user scripts installed?

Comment: OSX 10.10.5, Chrome 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit). No user scripts, and I tried disabling adblocker too, just in case.

Comment: No errors in the console. Behaviour reproduced on Chrome 52.0.2743.116 m on Windows 10.

Comment: I  updated the question with a couple of images showing the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click "show preview":

[image]

Comment: Well, I'm an idiot. Is this a new button? I swear I've never seen it before. If it's always been there I guess I must have mis-clicked it without realising.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It's always been there.

Comment: No defence then, I'm a 100% certified idiot :) Thanks